# How to select an object in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm beginner in JQuery, how could I select an object using JQuery ?

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Hide(senderID) {
   $("#" + senderID).hide(200);
   // this exception is thrown // Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
}

</script>

<div id="div1" onclick="javascript:Hide(this.id)"
```

Any help!

Comment: You're doing it correctly. What is the problem? (apart from your post missing closing DIV tag, script tag etc.)

Comment: can you add the line `alert(typeof $ + ' -- ' + typeof jQuery);` inside the Hide function at the beginning and post its outcome?

Comment: #Salman A: the message is: undefineddiv1undefined. seems there's a problem in the access to the JQuery files.

Answer (score 7):

- Don't:

  1. get an id from an element
  2. pass that id to a function
  3. use the id to get the element.
- Do: Just pass the element.
- Don't stick [`javascript:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) at the front of an intrinsic event attribute, it doesn't mean what you think it means.
- Don't use intrinsic event attributes for that matter (although I didn't fix this in this example). Use [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).
- Avoid triggering events based on clicks on a div. This can't be targeted with a focus based navigation device (such as using the tab key on the keyboard and numerous devices used by people with disabilities) without using new features introduced in HTML 5 that don't see widespread support yet. Use an element that is designed as an interaction control (such as a button). (Also not fixed in the example below)

Example:

```
function Hide(sender) {
       $(sender).hide(200);
}

<div id="div1" onclick="Hide(this)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Code is exactly the same as yours, I added the correct tags, and the call to include the jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function Hide(senderID) {
     $("#" + senderID).hide();
}
</script>
<div id="div1" onclick="javascript:Hide(this.id)">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Hide(sender) {
   $(sender).hide(200);
}
<div id="div1" onclick="javascript:Hide(this)"></div>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I can't resist. Why not use jQuery's full power?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hideable-div">Click me and get rid of me.</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.hideable-div').click(function () {
    $(this).hide(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you misplaced those "" in

```
<div id="div1" class=""hideable-div>Click me and get rid of me.</div>
```

Should be like

```
<div id="div1" class="hideable-div">Click me and get rid of me.</div>
```